# ThreeJS: does 3js modify uuid of objects in runtime?

Tags: three.js, uuid

Is it possible that 3js modify uuid of objects behind the scene? I thought that uuid is constant and only it may be changed manualy by developer.

Comment: downvote? That type of questions is not allowed or so?

Answer (score 3):

Please read the docs first, https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.id. It clearly says it is read-only.

Comment: I had read docs before I asked. I didn't noticed where it was mentioned that it was read only. There is only a note that it shouldn't be modify because it is auto-assigned. But it doesn't mean that it is not modified by threeJS behind a scene.

Comment: Modifying object id defeats the whole purpose of id.

Comment: it does but threejs team don't have to pay attention on that. Anyway thx.

Comment: No problem. I don't know what would you like to do exactly but maybe you could use .name or .userData instead of id.

Comment: @TomaszZieliński The question is about [`.uuid`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.uuid), not `.id`.

Comment: @ael have you tried to ask any three.js team member (for example [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/)) before making such a powerful statement about their attention on that?

Comment: @prisoner849 My bad, but what is the purpose of id if there is uuid?

Comment: @TomaszZieliński I didn't want to do anything with uuid, but its value was changed, so I was suprised and curious whether it was my mistake or some kind of threeJS internal behaviour.